# Database Compatibility Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've seen a situation that I couldn't explain, I hole you guys can give me a clue about it's reason.

I had a very "Not Optimized" query that has been written by one of our customers and based on our customers emails, It was running in less than 30 seconds before I change database compatibility level to 2016. after this change, I waited more than 2 hours but I didn't get any result from this query. After lots of struggles I changed back the database compatibility level to 2008 and everything fell on its right place.

Any body, any ideas? please!

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Without more details on the query it is hard to guess right!

Comment: If you have a question about a query, post the query, the table schemas and its execution plan. People can't guess what could be wrong when the only information is `it's slow`

Comment: SQL Server changed cardinality estimator between those versions. It might be the reason why it's so slow now.

Comment: Try to update statistics after changing the compatibility level and then run the query again. But without slow and fast the query's plans all our assumptions are sort of a divination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database compatibility level of SQL Server 2016 is 130, and SQL Server 2008's compatibility level is 100.

Here's the link about differences between compatibility level:

ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#differences-between-compatibility-level-130-and-level-140

We don't know your query. So I just guess that maybe your database is created at compatibility level 100. When you change your the compatibility level to 130 and run the query, the issue happens.

Compatibility level only affects the behavior of the specified database, not the entire server.

I hope it will be helpful to you.